# You do not have permission to call showModalDialog

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon, showmodaldialog, triggers

I am trying to code an add-on for my business domain.
When I test the add-on with Enabled (auth.Limited) I get "You do not have permission to call showModalDialog / prompt" error in onOpen.
 I am logged as owner.
 Any idea why that happens ? I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc here explains everything:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#opening

> When a document opens, it loads every add-on that the current user has installed or that any collaborator has enabled in the document, and calls each of their onOpen(e) functions.

This means that your showModalDialog / prompt will open every time a user opens a document which is not allowed.

If you really want to have a message for every time a document is open (users probably won't like this) then use a sidebar since in auth.Limited it is allowed, see the table here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#authorization_modes

Comment: thanks I've already seen that link but I've found it very confusing. I assumed this was the problem but I can't see the logic behind it. If I want to pop-up a message every time my user opens the add-on let me do it.

Comment: The problem is it is not just your add-on that is loaded onOpen.  What you can do is create a menu item that will let your prompt open, make it the first one the list and call it "Start Here" or something like that.

Comment: I was trying to hack a login system since Google Sheets doesn't share the free user's address with me for "privacy" purposes (I already shared the doc with that person so i already know his email , where on earth is the "privacy" issue ???) . So this is why I NEEDED to show the prompt on startup so nobody can edit without "logging" in. But since I posted the question I discovered the prompt can be closed with ESC anyway so I gave up the project. Simply can't be done on Google Sheets.